# Eclipse - how to remove light bulb on warnings

Tags: eclipse

Super quick question here that has been bugging me for a very long time -
Is there any way to remove the light bulb that appears on the left side of the line when there is a warning in Eclipse (Specifically using Java IDE, if it matters).

It is very annoying the way it hides breakpoints, and honestly - I can see the little squiggly yellow line just fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Go to `Windows > Preferences > General > Editors >  Text Editors > Annotations`. 
Select `Warnings` option in the `Annotation Types` list box, un-select `Vertical Ruler`

Comment: Thank you! that was very well hidden indeed :)

Comment: Dont think disabling warnings is a good idea. See @user2244676 's response below.

Comment: @Ragzitsu this solution doesn't *disable* warnings at all, it only disables the light bulb in the left vertical ruler for warnings. I used this approach and still have a warning list in the "Problems" tab and a yellow rectangle next to the scrollbar in the editor window. It seems to me that the difference between the two answers is that the one you refer to is specific to Java only and this one removes light bulbs for ALL warnings. Which one is more appropriate will depend on what the op/googler prefers.

Comment: Precisely what I wanted. I also got rid of the yellow underlining in the text editor in the same way. Warnings are still visible in the problems window and next to the scroll bar. But now I can see and add breakpoints!!

Comment: This gets rid of the warning light bulb - exactly what the OP (and I) needed. It doesn't get rid of the current line light bulb - see Oleksandr's answer for that.

Comment: damn man that f*ckin stupid bulb-exclamation was hiding my breakpoints under them for so many years. How the hell they dont understand breakpoints are more important and they should hide bulbs under breakpoints not the reverse

Answer (score 20):

`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor`

 Uncheck `Light bulb for quick assists`

[image: remove light bulb on warnings]

Comment: This was the answer that helped me.

Comment: This clears the lightbulb from the current line which was my next question. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try going to Window->Preferences menu. Then simply browse to Java->Errors/Warning panel. Expand the "Code Style" settings. Set the option you want to "ignore".

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think ignoring warnings is the right solution for  this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do this:

Button right into your code -> `Preferences...` -> `Java` -> `Editor` -> Disable the option: `Light bult for quick assists`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem generally occurs when you have installed multiple plugins in your eclipse.
I found the solution for that. 
Just Go to **Windows > Preferences > General > Editors >  Text Editors > Annotations** and then **Select Warnings option** in the Annotation Types list box, **un-select Vertical Ruler**