# How to import java web project into eclipse without warning tag?

Tags: java

[image]

Whenever I'm importing a project into my workplace, I get lots of warnings on web services.

Comment: What is the description of warning saying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Windows > Preferences > General > Editors >  Text Editors > Annotations. Select Warnings option in the Annotation Types list box, un-select Vertical Ruler

Taken via: 
[Eclipse - how to remove light bulb on warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896178/eclipse-how-to-remove-light-bulb-on-warnings)

Comment: Disabling warning won't help. They are there for a cuase.

Comment: Why suggest removing the warnings when we don't even know what they are? They could be indicating some issues no?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I understand, but sometime when we are keeping the header, footer and navigation independently, we mix up divs  and tags (though not a recommended practise)

Comment: yeah they are general tag warnings...i got it